# GBA SP screen suddenly turning darker for no reason

Tags: hardware, game-boy-advance

Hello all a few weeks ago I bought a GBA SP for well nostalgia and all that.
But now suddenly two issues have come up (One which I fixed I think).

Issue #1: The GBA SP suddenly turning off, checking some other sources this seem to be a battery issue. So I got a new battery and the issue is fixed for now. Or could there be some other cause?

Issue #2: Also the screen randomly turns dark, then when I flip it around a bit it gets at the normal brightness, after some testing it seems that the flipping the screen open/close again does fix the issue for a bit but after a few minutes the screen turns black. This is also before the battery change but after as well.

This makes me think that the screen backlight is broken, or could there be some other reason? Does anyone have tips on how to fix this? Any help would be appriciated.

Also my GBA SP model is AGS 001. Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Definitely sounds like something failing inside. Possibly backlight like you said. Personally, I'd just buy a "new" one. Fixing that sounds like more of a hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @DangerZone yeah I was afraid of that too :( well this one did come new out of the box in seal and all so thats a bummer. However would you know how to check / fix it>

Comment: @RDAxRoadkill Take a look at this: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/64713/The+screen+light+does+no+turn+on